# Parse XML from URL into python object

Tags: python, xml, django, xml-parsing, urllib2

The goodreads website has this API for accessing a user's 'shelves:' https://www.goodreads.com/review/list/20990068.xml?key=nGvCqaQ6tn9w4HNpW8kquw&v=2&shelf=toread

It returns XML. I'm trying to create a django project that shows books on a shelf from this API. I'm looking to find out how (or if there is a better way than) to write my view so I can pass an object to my template. Currently, this is what I'm doing:

```
import urllib2

def homepage(request):
    file = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.goodreads.com/review/list/20990068.xml?key=nGvCqaQ6tn9w4HNpW8kquw&v=2&shelf=toread')
    data = file.read()
    file.close()
    dom = parseString(data)
```

I'm not entirely sure how to manipulate this object if I'm doing this correctly. I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.travisglines.com/web-coding/python-xml-parser-tutorial).

Comment: Use [lxml objectify](http://lxml.de/objectify.html), it will parse the xml into Python objects.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I'd use [`xmltodict`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) to make a python dictionary out of the `XML` data structure and pass this dictionary to the template inside the context:

```
import urllib2
import xmltodict

def homepage(request):
    file = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.goodreads.com/review/list/20990068.xml?key=nGvCqaQ6tn9w4HNpW8kquw&v=2&shelf=toread')
    data = file.read()
    file.close()

    data = xmltodict.parse(data)
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', {'data': data})
```

Answer (score 12):

`xmltodict` using `urllib3`

```
import traceback
import urllib3
import xmltodict

def getxml():
    url = "https://yoursite/your.xml"

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()

    response = http.request('GET', url)
    try:
        data = xmltodict.parse(response.data)
    except:
        print("Failed to parse xml from response (%s)" % traceback.format_exc())
    return data
```

Answer (score 12):

`xmltodict` using `requests`

```
import requests
import xmltodict

url = "https://yoursite/your.xml"
response = requests.get(url)
data = xmltodict.parse(response.content)
```